# I'm new to ajax and jquery, I need some advice on how to pass a variable from a PHP to AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the right syntax for putting a variable from php to ajax

Here is my line of codes, I added a user_id inside the table 'events' but it wont save in database, without user_id it is saving in my database, now I want variable $user_id to be passed in the var user_id and then save it to database

```
select: function(start, end, allDay)
{
  var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
    if(title)
    {
      var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      var user_id = <?php echo $user_id ?>;
      $.ajax({
       url:"insert.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, user_id:user_id},
       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        alert("Added Successfully");
       }
     })
   }
},
```

Here is the Insert page.

```
<?php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=marchingdb', 'root', '');

if(isset($_POST["title"]))
{
 $query = "
 INSERT INTO events 
 (title, start_event, end_event,user_id) 
 VALUES (:title, :start_event, :end_event, :user_id)
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':title'  => $_POST['title'],
   ':start_event' => $_POST['start'],
   ':end_event' => $_POST['end'],
   ':user_id' => $_POST['user_id']
  )
 );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to achieve this using hidden input in HTML.

In HTML :

```
<input type='hidden' id='user_id' value='<?php echo $user_id; ?>' />
```

Above will create a hidden input in HTML.

To use the value in javascript. You can use the ID selector to fetch the value. 
For eg (jQuery) :

```
var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you sir It is saving now